# Center a label in a UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a WPF UserControl. I have inside a Label (autosized).

How I do for center the label in the middle of the UserControl?

Comment: Have you checked using `HorizontalContentAlignment=Center` and `HorizontalAlignment=Center`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use attributes: VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignement with the "Center" value.

Or you can have something like that:

```
Label.Margin = String.Format("{0},0,0,0",UserControl.actualWidth/2);
```

Comment: in actual Width you should calculate the labelActualWidth to really center it, but Horizontal and Vertical seems to work for me. Thanks.